Intellij - Prevent new line after Kotlin multi-line interface signature
I can't find where to turn off this annoying behavior of IntelliJ where it automatically adds a new line after my multiline method signature in interfaces.
Before auto-formatting:
interface Foo {
  fun method0()
  fun method1(
    arg1: Int,
    arg2: Int,
    arg3: Int,
  )
  fun method2()
}

After auto-formatting:
interface Foo {
  fun method0()
  fun method1(
    arg1: Int,
    arg2: Int,
    arg3: Int,
  )

  fun method2()
}

I don't want this new line.
